# Opening an application on a LAN desktop using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

After installing Cygwin on a windows LAN desktop, I can successfully connect through ssh using my below Python script:

```
 ssh.connect('135.24.237.142',username = 'cyg_server',password =    
 'sandforce')
 stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd")
 stdout.readlines()
 [u'/var/empty\n']
```

As a continuation, I would like to open an application on this desktop using Python script. For example I need to run the application: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tensilica\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3""  in the LAN desktop.

Please help how do I do this using ssh.

Regards,
Amitra

Comment: Have you tried simply `ssh.exec_command("C:\Program Files (x86)\Tensilica\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3")`?

Comment: Hi John, I am getting this when I tried with what you suggested: paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x2b2caf0L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>

Comment: @user3565150 If my answer solves this problem, don't forget to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in the script called test.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#test.py
import os
# you can change cmd to any command you want
cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tensilica\\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3"
os.system(cmd)
```

Then invoke it via ssh.

```
ssh.connect('135.24.237.142',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'sandforce')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("python test.py")
```

Comment: Due to the spaces in the command it might be necessary to quote it as '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tensilica\Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3"'

Comment: Pretty sure you'd want to use a raw string-- r"C:\Program FIles..."-- to escape the backslashes in there.

Comment: @clockwatcher How about double backslashes?

Comment: @m170897017 still trying with your solution...no results yet...how can I test whether I am able to browse through the directory structure of the LAN desktop?

Comment: @user3565150 You mean you want to browse but not invoke that program now?

Comment: @m170897017 No, I tried with your program. But in the remote dektop (135.24.237.142) the application did not open :(

Comment: @user3565150 Can you run this app successfully by hand? Does it in this path?

Comment: @m170897017 As you told, I have created test.py and from PyScripter I am running this: ssh.connect('135.24.237.142',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'sandforce')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("python test.py")

Comment: @user3565150 Is there any error message? Or just nothing happened?

Comment: @m170897017 there is no message at all, nothing happened. That is why I was thinking, how do I check whether I am actually connected. Can I change or go to a directory in the connected PC ?

Comment: @user3565150 You can change cmd in test.py to any command you want, dir/ipconfig for instance. (Remote is a windows, right?)

Comment: Yes remote is a windows (and mine too), I tried with that too...but still it does not output anything

Comment: @m170897017 I posted this link....but no replies yet: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28023411/revisions

Comment: @user3565150 Have you checked all the three output iterfaces, stdin/stdout/stderr ? There should be some outputs after executing the command.

Comment: Yes, I checked now...stdout.readlines() and also did stderr.readlines() and stdin.readlines()...but all are empty....nothing returned

Comment: @user3565150 That's strange. In your questioni, if cmd is pwd, you can get output in the stdout. But if you change cmd to dir or ipconfig, nothing returns? That dose not make sense.